# Inline If Statement In PHP

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I'm trying to working with inline if-statement but it's not working properly here is my code:

```
$subject_set = ($public) ? 'find_all_subjects()' : 'find_all_subjects(FALSE)';
```

Please tell me which thing i'm doing wrong in it and this is my normal statement:

```
if($public){$subject_set = find_all_subjects();}else{$subject_set = find_all_subjects(FALSE);}
```

Comment: $subject_set = ($public) ? (find_all_subjects()) : (find_all_subjects(FALSE));

Comment: You mean a ternary? Remove the quotes as shown by @iCoders

Comment: @iCoders kinldy post your answer because i want to make you best answer

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar.i have already posted .please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quote from function

```
 $subject_set = ($public) ? (find_all_subjects()) : (find_all_subjects(FALSE));
```

Answer (score 3):

to put it simply: `'find_all_subjects()'`  is a STRING, while `find_all_subjects()` is a function call.

remove the quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `''` for call function 
?

try this

```
$subject_set = ($public) ? find_all_subjects() : find_all_subjects(FALSE);
```